# Permanent address is old on my passport, what should be filled in the UK visa application form?

Tags: visas, uk

I plan to travel to UK but the permanent address on my passport is old one, moved from there few years back. I need to understand what address should I be putting in the visa application form. Will it be the old one that's on the passport or my current permanent address?

Answer (score 4):

Per the [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/424265/VAF1-GUIDANCE-NOTES.pdf), the visa form is asking for your current address, where you live now.

> This is the address where you live rather than your family home. You
>   MUST include your full residential address details including house
>   number or name/street/village/town/city/state/province/postal or
>   zip code/country.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned the current address. And all went through just fine.

Answer (score -1):

What's your citizenship and which country are you applying from? I don't know UK specifics, but generally in many Western countries there's no expectation that your passport will contain an accurate address (or in fact any address), it is understood that you're free to move about anywhere without officially registering, making a passport change, etc. So, I would guess that the address listed on the passport doesn't matter, and you should just list your real address on your application. However, the best thing to do would be to contact the consulate / visa office where you'll be applying, because sometimes there are strange rules specific to a particular country pair (e.g. it may be the case that in some countries your visa application will be delayed or will raise some red flags if you don't update your passport address to your real one before applying). I think the chances of something like this are small though.

Comment: I think the sweeping claim that "in Western countries ... you're free to move about without officially registering" overstates the facts quite a bit. Certainly both in Denmark and Sweden (my personal experience) one is obliged to inform the authorities where one lives. This is apparently not the case in most _English-speaking_ Western countries, but from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_registration) it looks like those are the exception, not the norm.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned the current address. And all went through just fine